# when does induction machine supply capacitive power

Tags: induction-motor

Can an induction machine whether it being a motor or a generator supply capacitive reactive power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A motor or generator consists of coils. Therefore, the voltage coming from the motor/generator will mainly be inductive reactive power.

Comment: This is not the case for synchronous motors or generators with a field coil (as opposed to permanent magnet).  The field can be adjusted to alter power factor.  An unloaded synchronous motor can even be used for power factor correction.  See [Synchronous condenser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_condenser)